# How to get html from web page in Django

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I was trying to implement some testing in Django, and I needed to check the data on the web page with a string, but I couldn't retrieve data from the web page. so, how can I get data(html) from web page?

my tests.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class TicketTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_user_details_on_ticket_id(self):

        response = self.client.get(f"/api/ticket/1")
        print(response.content) # this returns empty data in bytes

        # I want to check this
        #self.assertEquals(response.data, "helloworld")
```

Comment: Why don't you print out `response.status_code` and make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: @RedCricket because response.status_code just prints the status code and I want the actual data to verify

Comment: *"data(html)"* ... DRF return the data as JSON, What do you mean by HTML here?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I didn't knew that it returns the data in JSON. Can you please tell me how can I get the data in JSON?

Comment: I think the `self.assertEquals(response.data "helloworld")` will do the job. Have you tried that?

Comment: response has no attribute named data

Comment: hoe does the corresponding view look like?

Comment: what do you mean? can you please elaborate

Comment: The view that gets called when you access the endpoint `/api/ticket/1`

Comment: Actually, it's kind of complicated, so I'd like not to go there but I can assure you that there is json on `/api/ticket/1` webpage

Comment: I am sure the `response.data` should work as-is *if you are returning "proper DRF response"* from the view. In short, there is something wrong with the view's response.

Comment: But when I try to print response.data, python gives error saying that response has no attribute named data. And dir(response) also doesn't include "data". Are you sure, you're right?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. Personally, I am using `response.data` to check the response in my projects. I think you should add a ***minimal verifiable example*** to reproduce the issue so that someone else can help you.

Comment: Oh. I see. Also, the status code shows 301. that isn't good right?

Comment: it depends on your view

Comment: Actually, I got the error, It wasn't mistake from the views.py, but I was missing an slash at the end of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct. You can retrieve data from web page by using `response.content` . The problem is that you're missing a slash at the end of the url, so the url should be

```
 response = self.client.get(f"/api/ticket/1/")
```

instead of

```
 response = self.client.get(f"/api/ticket/1")
```